# How can I show data in UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a segmented control (2 segments) and I want to show data when I click each segment

if segmentcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==0
then show data from http://arproject.site90.com/jsonbuilding.php

if segmentcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex==1
then show data from http://arproject.site90.com/jsonshop.php

How can I show data in segment control?

Comment: Show data how? Are you talking about a new view controller, alert pop up, etc...?

Comment: new view controller, if you have any idea pls tell me

Comment: OK. Still not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Are you asking how to show a new view controller when the user touches one of the segment controls or how to show the JSON data (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code from my project that has to deal with what you are asking. I am new as well and needed help with this concept, here is a link that helped me, in case my code is not clear enough: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/29597-uisegmentedcontrol-tutoria.html

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlPressed:(id)sender {
if (self.measurementSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {
    self.waterLabel.text = @"Water (mL)";
    self.ratioLabel.text = @"Ratio (mL/g)";
    self.coffeeLabel.text = @"Coffee (g)";
    self.metricLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.metricLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.31 green:.31 blue:.31 alpha:1];
    self.metricLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    self.usLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.71 green:.71 blue:.71 alpha:1];
    self.usLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.31 green:.31 blue:.31 alpha:1];
    self.usLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    }

if (self.measurementSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==1) {
    self.waterLabel.text = @"Water (cups)";
    self.ratioLabel.text = @"Ratio (cups/Oz)";
    self.coffeeLabel.text = @"Coffee (Oz)";
    self.usLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.usLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.31 green:.31 blue:.31 alpha:1];
    self.usLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    self.metricLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.71 green:.71 blue:.71 alpha:1];
    self.metricLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.31 green:.31 blue:.31 alpha:1];
    self.metricLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    }
}
```

This enables control for this segmented control:
[image: Which enables control for this segmented control:]

Hope that this helps, good luck!